# How do I scrape img tags from 1mg webaite

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am trying to scrape the HTML of a webpage from [1mg](https://www.1mg.com/categories/ayurveda/top-brands-265?filter=true&brand=Dabur) website.

In the URL, when I try to save it as a HTML, or when I tried to scrape it using BeautifulSoup, I get `None` returned.

Code used for scraping:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
headers = {"User-Agent":'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.116 Safari/537.36'}
url='https://www.1mg.com/categories/ayurveda/top-brands-265?filter=true&brand=Dabur'
page= requests.get(url, headers=headers)
soup=BeautifulSoup(page.content,'html.parser')
img=soup.find_all('img',{'class':'style__image___Ny-Sa style__loaded___22epL'})
for i in img:
 i['src']
```

This is an example tag for the image to scrape:

```
 <img alt="Dabur Shilajit Gold Capsule" src="https://res.cloudinary.com/du8msdgbj/images/w_150,h_150,c_fit,q_auto,f_auto/v1603435745/feaoalhp4c6bv8icllgp/dabur-shilajit-gold-capsule.jpg" title="Dabur Shilajit Gold Capsule" class="style__image___Ny-Sa style__loaded___22epL">
```

I have copied the above tag manually as an example. I have used the same code(changed the tags) for the Product Name and Price it worked fine. I even tried using the parent tags of the img tag.

Answer (score 1):

The page is loaded dynamically, so `requests` won't support it. However the data is available in JSON format on the website, try using the built-in [`json`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) module to get all the images (a total of 40).

```
import json
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = "https://www.1mg.com/categories/ayurveda/top-brands-265?filter=true&brand=Dabur"

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(URL).content, "html.parser")
json_data = json.loads(
    soup.select_one("#content-container > div > div > div > script:nth-child(5)").string
)

for data in json_data["itemListElement"]:
    print(data["image"])
```

Output:

```
https://res.cloudinary.com/du8msdgbj/images/w_150,h_150,c_fit,q_auto,f_auto/v1603435745/feaoalhp4c6bv8icllgp/dabur-shilajit-gold-capsule.jpg
https://res.cloudinary.com/du8msdgbj/images/w_150,h_150,c_fit,q_auto,f_auto/v1500611141/wwkoja9giavml3tgyza4/dabur-musli-pak-laghu.jpg
..All the way until

https://res.cloudinary.com/du8msdgbj/images/w_150,h_150,c_fit,q_auto,f_auto/v1601446598/sujrsvjyzcuvpfwtekhz/anti-oxidants-combo-of-organic-india-tulsi-ginger-turmeric-25-tea-bag-and-dabur-honey-squeezy-225gm-buy-1-get-1-free.png
```